# Jenkins - Mandatory Pre-build Step - All Builds/Projects

Tags: jenkins, build, hidden, pre-build-event

Is there a way to create a hidden build step, so Jenkins will always execute a specific script when a build is run?

Essentially we are trying to enforce the standard process of builds onto the users.

Comment: Thanks. It's more of a how we could do it conceptually. I've considered using plugins that use multi-build so you could tie jobs together, but there are implications behind that and you could never really enforce a job to run.

We ideally want something that will run as standard hidden from the user of a build.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Jenkins Template Plugin](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/02/using-jenkins-templates-plugin-to.html) would suit your needs.  I haven't tried it, but it seems like it is solving the problems you are describing.  Note, however, that it is a  [Jenkins Enterprise](http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise-by-cloudbees-overview.cb) plugin, so it's not free.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly this is not an option for us to install enterprise plugins.